# Python: how to know which database I am connecting to?

Tags: python, sql

I have a very odd problem. I am able to access a database because someone installed the right ODBC drivers on my computer, but I dont know

- what type of ODBC drivers are installed
- which flavor of SQL is it

All I can do is

```
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DSN=MYDSN')
sql = "SELECT * FROM MASTER.PRICES"
cursor.execute(sql)
data = cursor.fetchone()
```

which returns some data.

But thats all I know. Which SQL command can I run to know more about this mysterious database?

Thanks!

Comment: You probably have an odbc.ini file somewhere with the MYDSN alias configured and all the details your are looking for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`pyodbc` provides the [`getinfo`](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Connection#getinfo) method.

```
>>> cnxn.getinfo(pyodbc.SQL_DBMS_NAME)
'MySQL'
>>> cnxn.getinfo(pyodbc.SQL_DBMS_VER)
'10.1.21-MariaDB'
>>> cnxn.getinfo(pyodbc.SQL_DRIVER_NAME)
'libmyodbc5w.so'
```

Here are just a few examples, you can find all the available constants in the [documentation](https://mkleehammer.github.io/pyodbc/api-connection.html#getinfo).

Comment: magnifique mon cher ami

Comment: was my frenchness so obvious or did you check my profile? :)

Comment: "julien"? are you kidding :D

Comment: arf, never thought about that ^^'

Comment: btw I see `cnxn.getinfo(pyodbc.SQL_DRIVER_NAME)
Out[9]: 'Cisco Information Server 7.0.3 ODBC Driver'`. what the hell is that?

Comment: I think your reference URL is outdated. You can replace it with the following. All constants are defined here: https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/blob/ceeab39598b62d83ad56c9b16a9f40042bb4e766/src/connection.cpp#L614